# Why are my two chained monitors just mirrored and not detectable?

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad, displayport, docking-station

I connected the following components:

Lenovo Thinkpad T450s <-USB-> Thinkpad USB 3.0 Pro Dock <-DP--mDp->Dell U2414H <-DP--mDp-> Dell U2415

The two displays are mirrored but I can't detect them in the windows display settings.
Drivers are up-to-date.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the daisy-chaining to work correctly, it needs to use DisplayPort 1.2.

I think that your U2414H monitor "does" support DisplayPort 1.2. But, as it seems from several forum posts all over, it is not set that way by default.

So, what I'd suggest you is to try to find in the U2414H monitor menu the setting to switch it from DP 1.1 to DP 1.2.

Comment: Hell yeah!! enabling DisplayPort 1.2 worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quote from [a manual I found online](https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1030207531.pdf), page 8:

> **Using the DP output connector**
>
> You can connect one external monitor to the ultra dock by using the DP output connector

It probably doesn't support DisplayPort 1.2 which is required for daisy-chaining.

Comment: thanks for the hint. any suggestions for a docking station which would support daisy chaining?

Comment: I don't know of any particular docking station models that support it, but you should look for the keyword *MST* (Multi-Stream Transport).

Answer (score 0):

The Lenovo P24q-10 has an actual setting called "DP Daisy chain" that must be set to on to allow extending the desktop. I'd assume that if the monitor has a DP out it would support the spec but...

Also, you will want to turn the daisy chaining on for the last monitor in the chain first. The menu has a tendency to disappear if the monitor isn't getting a signal.